# Get processor info with wmic - format error

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

When I try to get the number of cores and logical processors in one shot, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Format:List
Invalid GET Expression.
```

How can I format this correctly to get the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the list of field names in quotes and remove the space between them:

```
wmic cpu get "NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors" /Format:List
```

Better yet, drop `wmic` and use `Get-WmiObject` if you're using PowerShell anyway:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor |
    Select-Object NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors |
    Format-List
```

Comment: Agree - `wmic` is not needed at all in PowerShell now that we have WMI and CIM cmdlets.